# how to refresh a one customer page after request accepted by second customer

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am creating web based app to find customer near your selected area. after selecting area i am sending request to the customer and checking that within 2 minutes requested customer is accepting request or not.

In my earlier solution i created one API. In which after each 5 seconds i am sending request to my MYSQL database to check value is updated or not. but in this case load of database is continuously increasing due to more request and traffic.

can anyone suggest me a better solution to reduce load time of mysql database?

Comment: Use Node js or User Redis or any cache system to store and check

Answer (score 0):

You can use long polling. By Creating An Open Connection To Server.

Here is a Example:

```js
(function poll(){
    $.ajax({ url: "index.php?a=1", success: function(data){
        //HANDLE RESPONSE AS YOU NEED;
    }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 30000 });
})();
```

In Index.php

```
//add this at top to create open connection
set_time_limit(0);
if($_GET['a']){
$data = array("status"=>200,"data"=>$response_array);
echo json_encode($data);
die;
}
```

I just give this example to show how to use long polling. To know more about long polling please checkout [here](https://github.com/panique/php-long-polling)